# user does not exist in /etc/passwd when trying to change the default shell

Tags: passwd, chsh

I want to change my default shell from tcsh to bash. So I tried and this is what happened:

```
>sudo chsh userid
Changing the login shell for userid
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Login Shell [/xhbin/tcsh]: /bin/bash
chsh: user 'userid' does not exist in /etc/passwd
```

Indeed, I am not in /etc/passwd. I don't know why.

What can I do?

Comment: Is your system using distributed authentication (e.g. kerberos / winbind)? In that case your user details would not appear in the local /etc/passwd file (but should be visible using `getent passwd <userid>`). I think that whether running `chsh` is supported in that case may depend on settings in `/etc/pam.d/`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My computer is part of a network using distributed authentication, so my user details would not appear in the local /etc/passwd file (but are visible using getent passwd userid) (thanks @steeldriver).
In my case I had to do chsh on a core machine.

Comment: can you explain what a "core machine" is?

Comment: In my case I'm referring to a set of dedicated machines provided by the university inside their network that students can log into and use (shared). As opposed to my own machine in my office.

Comment: @rmp251 This is exactly my scenario is. I don't have access to the core machine. Did you find a way to change the shell otherwise?

Comment: @Geek did you find the way how to solve it?

Comment: Better late than never. My workaround was to open my terminal preference, select the Unnamed profile, in the "Command" menu, check the box "Run a custom command instead of my shell" and type "/bin/zsh" as command

Comment: Being on an AWS WorkSpaces Linux machine, I had no access to the core machine but the instructions from @befabry worked perfectly.  Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 31):

There is a workaround for `gnome-terminal`:

1. Go to *Edit* → *Profile preferences* → *Title and Command*.
2. Check *Run a custom command instead of my shell*.
3. Provide `bash` as the *Custom command* (or `fish`, or anything).

Comment: Thanks! Supplying a command to run immediately when I open my terminal (or new terminal tab) via the settings worked for me.

Comment: This also works for Konsole and yakuake in KDE.

Comment: Great Answer. I was looking for ways to make zsh as my default one, and the other solutions was to edit the /etc/passwd file, which was not a good thing. This works like butter.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue with AWS Workspaces Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 14):

If you are trying to ssh into a remote host with a domain user, you might not be able to change your shell using `chsh` as @Masoud mentioned. But here is a simple workaround for this case - whenever you ssh into the machine, do this:

`ssh my-host -t "zsh --login"`

or

`ssh my-host -t "cd /data/repos; zsh --login"`

If you also want to login directly into a different working dir.

**Edit**:

Another simple option that does not require ssh command manipulation:

- Edit your profile file: `vi ~/.profile`
- Launch your favorite shall by calling it at the last line, e.g. `zsh`
- Save and quit (`:wq`)

This solution also has the advantage that it persists when creating new sub-shells, for example when using `tmux`.

Comment: Every time I need to exit the terminal session, I need to exit twice (one from zsh and once from bash). Is there any workaround for this issue? Edit: The workaround is to use this answer instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1370050/749219

Answer (score 12):

If you are using LDAP authentication by PAM or something, you have to find your answer in your LDAP Server. Let's aim it for Microsoft AD, in which case your domain account is not in `/etc/passwd` when you log in, but you can see your user property in AD, by `getent passwd | grep user`.

If at the end it shows your shell is `/bin/csh`, that's because in your AD there is a attribute for that. So if you have administrator account on AD, you can fix it yourself. Otherwise just tell your AD admin to enable advance features in the *View* tab of *Active directory users and computers > User properties > UNIX attributes*. There you can change the login shell to `/bin/bash`.

Be sure you don't forget to run:

```
sudo /opt/pbis/bin/config LoginShellTemplate /bin/bash
```

*Source: [User does not exist in /etc/passwd when trying to change the default shell](https://web.archive.org/web/20150814010728/http://www.fereidonian.net/?p=52).*

Comment: Question was to change shell for one user, whereas pbis config changes for all users.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the shell for your user, you do not need to become root. Just type:

```
chsh
```

without `sudo` and without arguments.

---

See also `man chsh`:

```
The chsh command changes the user login shell. This determines the name
of the user's initial login command. A normal user may only change the
login shell for her own account; the superuser may change the login
shell for any account.
```

Comment: The reason I used sudo was because it didn't do anything without it.

    `> whoami
    userid
    > chsh
    You may not change the shell for 'userid'.`

Comment: The reason it works is that chsh does not work with kerberos

Comment: Still fails: `chsh: user "walshcaadmin" does not exist.`

Answer (score 4):

My machine is using LDAP authentication and I don't have access to the server. So my workaround was to change $SHELL variable to zsh at the end of my .bashrc file.
`$SHELL=/bin/zsh`
`$SHELL`
So for me when I open terminal bash opens zsh.

Answer (score 2):

If you forgot your user name, you can use `whoami` command to remember you.

So, try with:

```
sudo chsh $(whoami)
```

If indeed, doesn't exist a line starting with your user name in `/etc/passwd` file (which seems inexplicable), you can add a new one like this:

```
username:x:1000:1000:your real name,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash
```

See also: [Understanding /etc/passwd File Format](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/).

Comment: One reason your user might not exist in /etc/passwd is if authentication is not handled on that machine (e.g. ldap)

Answer (score 2):

Open the file ~/.bashrc and add this at the end :

```bsh
# Run zsh
if [ "$SHELL" != "/usr/bin/zsh" ]
then
    export SHELL="/usr/bin/zsh"
    exec /usr/bin/zsh
fi
```

Don't forget to configure zsh :

- By typing "zsh" in a bash terminal.
- Or by creating the file ~/.zshrc with default content

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292612/6441900) answer helped me.

In your `~/.profile` add

```
if [ "$SHELL" != "/bin/bash" ]
then
    export SHELL="/bin/bash"
    exec /bin/bash -l    # -l: login shell again
fi
```

Or whatever other shell you want to use

Answer (score 0):

the solution for active directory accounts is as follows:

$vim ~/.bashrc

and add this at the end :

if [ "$SHELL" != "/usr/bin/zsh" ]
then
export SHELL="/usr/bin/zsh"
exec /usr/bin/zsh
fi

Comment: Hello. How is this a answer to the question that was asked?