# chsh always asking a password , and get `PAM: Authentication failure`

Tags: command-line, password, chsh

Today I tried to switch to another shell.

First I tried fish, and used `chsh -s fish` to change fish to default. After some time I found it cannot use `~/.bashrc` (&& needs to be replaced by and).

Because I prefer to reusing `~/.bashrc`, I found `zsh` which seems an easier one and followed [this documentation](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) to switch to `zsh`.

While I was running `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`, suddenly it asked me to enter `Password:`. I entered the root password but got `PAM: Authentication failure`.

Then I tried `chsh -s bash` and `chsh -s zsh`, it always asked me for a password and threw `PAM: Authentication failure` (not system password). I can't figure this out.

Comment: Check if you have an alias or something with sudo in your .bashrc/.zshrc/.etcrc

Comment: This is obviously a bug: I have to enter my password even as root, and the correct password still leads to a permission denied. Sudo must not be invoked when the user is already root.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Thanks to [this question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/202468/changing-the-shell-using-chsh-via-the-command-line-in-a-script), I worked around this by:

Replacing

```
auth       required   pam_shells.so
```

with

```
auth       sufficient   pam_shells.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/chsh`.

Then it doesn't ask for a password anymore.
But I think it better to restore chsh settings after switching the shell.

Comment: using sed: sudo sed s/required/sufficient/g -i /etc/pam.d/chsh

Comment: Did unfortunately not work. But I commented that line out, changed the shell and removed the comment, again. So your hint was the right one for me.

Answer (score 37):

Try this:

```
sudo chsh -s $(which zsh) $(whoami)
```

Comment: this is the way

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `"sudo chsh -s /bin/zsh {{ created_user }}"` with ansible works like a charm (Thank you)

Answer (score 8):

1. Use `which zsh`to find your `zsh` location.

   ```
   $ which zsh
   /usr/bin/zsh
   ```
2. Add `/usr/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells`
3. Check in `/etc/passwd` that your config is `/usr/bin/zsh`
4. Run `chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: This only works for the normal user, but not for `root`. Is it a security feature?

Comment: could you expand on step 3 please, what if it isn't there?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate work around –

My `/etc/pam.d/chsh` file has this section:

```
# This allows root to change user shell without being
# prompted for a password
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
```

As the comment suggests, it lets root change the shell without needing to product the password. As such I was able to change my shell (to zsh) by running `chsh` as root and specifying my user account, eg:

```sh
sudo chsh $USER -s $(which zsh)
```

Comment: For me, comment out this line: `# auth       required   pam_shells.so` , then run `chsh`, then uncomment that line back.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding at bottom of your $HOME/.bashrc

```sh
export SHELL=`which sh`
zsh
exit
```

This works for me! if you want you can put a welcome text in your shell, but you must install figlet using:

```sh
sudo apt install figlet
```

And overwrite the previous code at bottom of your $HOME/.bashrc

```sh
export SHELL=`which zsh`
figlet 'Your welcome message LIKE FOR ME: Welcome'
zsh
exit
```

Comment: nice, quick and easy.  The first line where you export should be
export SHELL=`which zsh`
as in the second block, not which sh

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when [switching to `fish`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#switching-to-fish). I accidentally executed `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish` while on my system it should have been `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`, but even though the first command warned that the shell did not exist, it still changed it to `/usr/local/bin/fish` in `/etc/passwd`. This meant that the second, correct, command failed to authenticate (just like new SSH logins) as the shell did not exist.

The solution for me was to first correct the shell to an existing one in `/etc/passwd`, and then run the correct `chsh` command again.

Answer (score 0):

For those for whom the top two solutions did not work. I've found my solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/950531/1168898

> There is a workaround for `gnome-terminal`:
>
> 1. Go to *Edit* → *Profile preferences* → *Title and Command*.
> 2. Check *Run a custom command instead of my shell*.
> 3. Provide `bash` as the *Custom command* (or `fish`, or anything).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```sh
grep -qxF "$(which zsh)" "/etc/shells" || sudo bash -c "echo $(which zsh) >> /etc/shells"
grep -qxF "$(which zsh)" "/etc/shells" && sudo chsh -s "$(which zsh)" "$(whoami)"
```

1. Check whether `/etc/shells` contains the `zsh` executable you want. If it doesn't, append it to the file.
2. If `/etc/shells` contains the shell you want, change your user's shell to that.

I have some parts abstracted into variables but for simplicity's sake, I included the full logic as plainly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i try to change my shell, what i did is go to your `/etc/shells` , find your user and than change the /bin/bash for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SCP/SFTP/rysnc, be **very cautious** when making changes to your shell startup. These tools will FAIL in a very difficult to troubleshoot way if anything is printed at login. Better yet, just use the chsh solution and do it the right way.

To work around this, make sure that your non-interactive shell login will be silent by wrapping your ZSH customizations inside a check for interactive. For example, based on the above answer by @Alpha for Bash, this is the modified .bashrc to support both remote file transfers and ZSH for interactive logins:

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
  export SHELL=`which sh`
  zsh
fi
```