# What is the correct way to allow accounts without passwords to chsh?

Tags: password, pam, shadow, chsh

I hope I have phrased this question correctly, it's a bit of an odd one.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 host with many users on it. All of the users log into their account on the host via SSH public key. All accounts have no password. This means that the `/etc/shadow` entry for every user is `!`. (I *do not* mean to imply that any account has an *empty* password, which would mean anyone could enter a username and then hit Enter at the password prompt to log in. An account with *no* password and an account with an *empty* password are very different things!)

With this situation, users are unable to set a password for their account with `passwd` because changing your password requires entering the current one which they can't do. This is actually fine.

However, another thing they can't do is change their shell because doing this requires entering a password, which the accounts don't have.

[One solution I found](https://askubuntu.com/a/812426) suggests replacing `required` with `sufficient` in this line in `/etc/pam.d/cshs`:

```
# This will not allow a user to change their shell unless
# their current one is listed in /etc/shells. This keeps
# accounts with special shells from changing them.
auth       required   pam_shells.so
```

This works but my concerns with this are:

1. I don't understand *why* this works in my case because users' shells are *already* in `/etc/shells`. So why does modifying this suddenly allow users to use `chsh` without a password? (To be clear, in all cases, the users' current shells and desired shells are both listed in `/etc/shells`.)
2. I don't necessarily want service accounts to be able to change their own service-specific shells although this isn't quite as important.

I feel like this is something than can be solved by PAM in a more elegant way, somehow.

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem! Did you come to a clean solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That change works, to some extent, but your first concern is because it works somewhat inadvertently.  A `required` control for PAM auth checks something, then, if the check succeeds, moves to the next check.  A `sufficient` control checks something, and if the check succeeds (and no previous check has failed), immediately has PAM succeed.  Thus, it isn't whether the shell is in `/etc/shells` that matters in your case.  The shells are always there, and the check always succeeds: changing `required` to `sufficient` means that that success skips everything later, including the password entry.

So, to have more reasonable `chsh` access, all you need to do is keep `pam_shells.so` as `required`, and add some *other* check after it, with that check being `sufficient`.  Some options include:

- Allow passwordless changes if the user is not a system user: `auth sufficient pam_usertype.so isregular` (see the pam_usertype.so manpage for how it decides on the user type).
- Allow passwordless changes if the user is in the `users` group: `auth sufficient pam_wheel.so trust group=users` (adapted from [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/202468/changing-the-shell-using-chsh-via-the-command-line-in-a-script)).