# Unable to login to root after running ansible scripts

Tags: su, ansible, chsh

I am currently not able to login to my super user. Here is the sequence of events

```bash
~ su  
password:  
su: using restricted shell which zsh  
su: failed to execute which zsh: No such file or directory
```

Previously I was trying to automate with ansible.

```yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  tasks: 
  - name: Install zsh
    apt: name=zsh
  - name: change shell
    shell: chsh -s `which zsh`
  - name: Install ohmyzsh autosuggestions plugin
    ansible.builtin.git:
      repo: 'https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions.git ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions'
      dest: "~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions"
  - name: Update our zshrc
    shell: sed -i 's/(git/(git zsh-autosuggestions' ~/.zshrc
```

When I was running my playbook, sometimes it would fail on the tasks portion

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed_modules": {"ansible.legacy.setup": {"failed": true, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: ansible.legacy.setup\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

and sometimes it gets to the chsh section (I think its when I change my shell or create an alias for python or change the ansible script (get rid of certain steps). I don't fully understand it but it gives me this error for the chsh section

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "chsh -s `which zsh`", "delta": "0:00:00.006789", "end": "2023-08-03 19:46:19.294159", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-08-03 19:46:19.287370", "stderr": "Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure", "stderr_lines": ["Password: chsh: PAM: Authentication failure"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Overall there are two things I would like to fix, for one by super user account, but secondly the ansible script so this does not happen again

Comment: Figured out how to fix the issue, although I am not too sure why this issue happened. Turns out I was not able to login to my root user (PAM authentication error) so I ended up using https://askubuntu.com/questions/812420/chsh-always-asking-a-password-and-get-pam-authentication-failure to fix the issue. If anyone knows why this happened or helped please let me know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chsh always asking a password , and get \`PAM: Authentication failure\`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812420/chsh-always-asking-a-password-and-get-pam-authentication-failure)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `which zsh` in this ansible task

```
- name: change shell
    shell: chsh -s `which zsh`
```

was not evaluated and the default shell was set to `which zsh` instead of the path to zsh. You set the login shell for root to something that does not exist. When you log in as root, it tries to find a login shell called `which zsh`, can't find it and gives up.

You could change the task to use a fixed path, something like this:

```
- name: change shell
    shell: chsh -s /path/to/zsh
```

If you're running the playbook on different systems where the path to `zsh` varies, you could read it to a variable in a separate task before running the "change shell" task.